# Back to page using ajax form with form settings

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that offers the user results. From that page there are additional sort options and advanced search options that are submitted by POST by AJAX to a script and the output is inserted into a div using jquery.

Once the user clicks one of the results, they are redirected to the details page. When I click back from that page it doesnt load says form submission error.

Not sure what to be looking for all the stuff I have seen is for when there are simply multiple ajax pages in one page.

Comment: you can add those values to cookie with field ids and recollect from there.

Comment: Sounds messy The form has about 17 variables.

Comment: the choice u have is to add those data to a memory and fetch from there. U can either user the browser memory or cookies or session

Comment: How do you use browser memory? sounds interesting.